# Tortoise and Hare algorithm returning empty result for one case and incorrect for repeated characters

Tags: algorithm

I was going through [Wikipedia implementation of Cycle detection using Tortoise-and-Hare algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare). Using Ruby language, this is what I implemented:

```
def tortoise_and_hare(sequence)
  tortoise = 1
  hare = 2
  while sequence[tortoise] != sequence[hare]
    tortoise += 1
    hare += 2
  end

  # Find start index of first repetition
  idx = 0
  tortoise = 0
  while sequence[tortoise] != sequence[hare]
    tortoise += 1
    hare += 1
    idx += 1
  end

  # Find length of cycle starting from index idx
  length = 1
  hare = tortoise + 1
  while sequence[tortoise] != sequence[hare]
    hare += 1
    length += 1
  end

  [idx, length]
end

sequence = [2, 0, 6, 3, 1, 6, 3, 1, 6, 3, 1]
idx, length = tortoise_and_hare(sequence)
p sequence[idx, length]
```

This is working correctly and returns `[6, 3, 1]`. Now,

1. If I trim the sequence to `[2, 0, 6, 3, 1, 6, 3, 1]`, it returns
   empty set.
2. I can see the problem is in second loop. If cycle has
   repeating character, algorithm returns incorrect answer. Example,
   `[2, 0, 6, 3, 1, 6, 6, 3, 1, 6, 6, 3, 1, 6]` returns `[6, 3, 1]`,
   but should be `[6, 3, 1, 6]`. I can see the problem is in third
   loop.

So I guess my questions are:

1. Is the algorithm posted on Wikipedia standard?
2. Is my second case incorrect? I know cycle detection means infinitesimally long sequence which my exam is not, but it still has a cycle.
3. If the case is correct, what can we do to improve the algorithm and solve the 2 issues I pointed out above?

I tried modifying second loop for first problem (trimming the sequence small enough for the algorithm to fail) and it worked:

```
  # Find start index of first repetition
  idx = 0
  tortoise = 0
  while sequence[tortoise] != sequence[hare]
    tortoise += 1
    hare += 1
    hare = tortoise if hare > sequence.length - 1
    idx += 1
  end
```

1. Does it look wrong or may fail in some case?
2. What can we do for second problem (repeating characters)?

Although I cam up with another elegant Regex based solution, I still would like to learn more about above algorithm.

Regex solution for curious: `/(?<cycle>(\d+\s)+(\d+))\s\k<cycle>/`

Edit: I understood why it is impossible for it to detect repeated characters. But is there any other algorithm that may help in this situation?

Comment: Okay, I understood why it is impossible for this algorithm to work in case of repeated characters. Is there any algorithm which may work in this case?

Comment: Since you don't have any answers, instead of commenting on your question with another question, why not update your question to reflect your current question.

Comment: @xaxxon, edited. It didn't occur to me.

Comment: Also, I don't even want to think about the runtime complexity of that regex solution.  It may seem "elegant", but the backtracking on that has got to be horrendous.  Probably N! runtime or something similarly egregious!  It's going to eat your entire dataset and then look for a repeat.  It's going to spit out one number and try again.  It'll then spit out a second number and try again, repeating until the initial capture is empty.  I'm not even sure this will give you what you want.

Comment: So actually I think the regex solution is N^2 worst case.  Also, for an input of 1 1 1 1 1 1, I believe this will return you a repetition of "1 1 1", not just "1".  You'd have to make sure your input had exactly 2 cycles of the range present to get the minimal answer.  For an input of "1 1", I don't believe it will find any cycles, since it requires two numbers to be detected to match the first matching group.

Comment: I'm going to go to bed, but repeated numbers followed by different numbers are not valid input to the algorithm.  The mapping is from each valid entry in the range to the next one, using that next one as the key to determine the one afte that.  It is impossible for a number (say 6) to map to 6 on one stepping but to map to something else on the next step.  As soon as you go from a number to itself, the entirety of the rest of the data set must be that same number forever.  i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, .... once you repeat any number for the first time, you MUST be in a cycle.

Comment: And for a super easy solution, just look and see if you see the first number anywhere else in the array.  If not, check for the second number.  It's way simpler than your regex and has the same runtime.  You can also never check more than the size of your range of values beyond the number you're looking at.  If you haven't found it in that space, it CANNOT occur anywhere else (assuming a valid input, of course)

Comment: Regex was something I just tried few minutes ago. But yes, you are right, for many cases, it is giving weird answers.

Comment: I think if you just add some non-greediness to it, it will likely be faster and more accurate.  Not sure if always correct, though.  Also, you can use regex, but all you really need is the location of the first duplicate character, so matching a single number followed by 0 or more numbers followed by the first number is the regex you want.  Then use the positions of the matches (I think that's available in most implementations) to determine the actual contents of a cycle.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that your code is fine, but your sample set is too small.  The algorithm doesn't claim to find a cycle in the shortest amount of data possible.

The definition of the data set on the page you linked defines a process for generating an infinite set of data.  This data must eventually repeat, as your domain is unlimited, but your range is finite.

Depending on the range, more or less data will be required by this algorithm to determine the cycle.  You just have no longer provided it enough.

As for the solution I would go with?  I would create a map of each number in the range and the position at which I found it starting by inserting the first number.  As soon as you find a repeat, you've found your cycle.  From the position of the first instance to the position right before the second instance.  This gives linear runtime and N*M memory usage.  N=size of list M=range of values

Here's the perl (rusty perl) regex you want:

```
$data = "1 2 3 4 5 3 4 5"; 
if ($data =~ /(?<c>\d).*?(\k<c>)/) {
    print substr($data, $-[1], $-[2]-$-[1])."\n";
} elsif {
    print "NO\n";
}
```

The worst-case runtime on this is n^2 and I suppose it only works for single-digit numbers (easily fixed), but it's more straighforward.

Comment: I was actually working on [CodeEval problem here](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/5/). The original algorithm is giving empty results. Since we do not know the test cases, I am assuming that test cases are not long enough for the algorithm. I will try and look for another method apart from RegEx.

Comment: if your input isn't of the form of the input for these algorithms, then the algorithms are not the ones you are looking for.  That's why the page you linked to specifically called out the source of data.  You can't just disregard it.

Comment: @HarshGupta it turns out the problem in this question is actually harder than the problem posed on the link you provided.  However, regular expressions ARE a good approach for this specific problem.